# Building adjacency lists

Tags: c++

I have been trying to build a simple graph with adjacency lists.
Here's my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int> >adj_list;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::vector<int>v;
        adj_list.push_back(v);
    }
    int e;
    cout << "enter the no of edges" << endl;
    cin >> e;
    for (int i = 0; i < e; i++)
    {
        int a, b;
        cin >> a >> b;
        adj_list[a].push_back(b);
        adj_list[b].push_back(a);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < adj_list[i].size(); i++)
        {
            cout << adj_list[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

for the input as following``

- 4
- 1 2
- 1 3
- 2 3
- 3 4

the output I got is

- 2 1 1 3

with an error Debug assertion failed ,Expression:vector subscript out of range.
I am using visual studio 2015

Comment: visual studio 2015 has a very nive debugger, try it.

Comment: As jpo38 wrote please run it at least once with the debugger. Also, using better variables names would increase the chance you find the problem on your own

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
for (int j = 0; j < adj_list[i].size(); i++)
```

should be:

```
for (int j = 0; j < adj_list[i].size(); j++)  // <-- You incremented i instead of j
```

Also, to be safe, the outer loop should also loop on `size()` and not on a hard-coded `5`:

```
for (int i = 1; i < adj_list.size(); ++i)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < adj_list[i].size(); ++j)
   { ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Also, to remove the chance of getting the indices wrong, use the range-based `for` loop.

```
for(const std::vector<int>& v : adj_list) 
{
    for (int n : v)
        cout << n << " ";
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks the second idea fixed my problem.

Comment: And there should be validation on `e`.